# Lazy evaluation in objective c assignment?

Tags: objective-c, variable-assignment, lazy-evaluation

Will doSomeCalculations be called if a is nil?

`a.position = [self doSomeCalculations];`

I guess it has to as doSomeCalculations can alter the state, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `position` is a property and you rewrite the statement to the equivalent bracket syntax, you end up with:

```
[a setPosition:[self doSomeCalculations]];
```

No lazy evaluation is performed here. It's not any different from nested function calls when you consider that all these bracketed expressions are transformed into function calls to `objc_msgSend()`:

```
objc_msgSend(a, sel_getUid("setPosition:"), objc_msgSend(self, sel_getUid("doSomeCalculations")));
```

The bottom line is, `[self doSomeCalulations]` is evaluated even if `a` is `nil`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are assigning whatever `[self doSomeCalculations]` will return to `a.position` regardless if it's nil or not.

Also it could depend if you have written your own accessor for position but if you have used a `@synthesize`d accessor it will be assigned.